# OpenShift Django project deployment fails: "error: can't create or remove files in install directory"

Tags: python, virtualenv, openshift

I was updating my project after a long inactivity, and something got broken. Deployment failed and application wasn't restarted after `git push`.

I can still start my app manually by running `gear start`, but deployment steps which are needed to install packages from `install_requires` fail.

Here are parts of `gear deploy` output:

```
Activating virtenv
Running setup.py script..
running develop
error: can't create or remove files in install directory

The following error occurred while trying to add or remove files in the
installation directory:

    [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/test-easy-install-358943.write-test'

The installation directory you specified (via --install-dir, --prefix, or
the distutils default setting) was:

    /usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/

Perhaps your account does not have write access to this directory?  If the
installation directory is a system-owned directory, you may need to sign in
as the administrator or "root" account.  If you do not have administrative
access to this machine, you may wish to choose a different installation
directory, preferably one that is listed in your PYTHONPATH environment
variable.

For information on other options, you may wish to consult the
documentation at:

  http://peak.telecommunity.com/EasyInstall.html

Please make the appropriate changes for your system and try again.
```

And, later:

```
Running collectstatic...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "~/app-root/runtime/repo//wsgi/music/manage.py", line 2, in <module>
    from django.core.management import execute_manager
ImportError: No module named django.core.management
```

I tried to enable venv and run setup.py manually:

```
source $OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DIR/virtenv/bin/activate
export PYTHON_EGG_CACHE=$OPENSHIFT_GEAR_DIR/virtenv/lib/python-2.6
~/app-root/repo/setup.py develop
```

However, it resulted in the same `can't create or remove files in install directory` error. And I can't run `manage.py` in this environment like I did earlier, as well.

It seems to me that something happened to venv, but, then, `gear start` uses it too, and it still works...

Can anybody give me highlights about this problem?

P.S. I'm using a Python 2.6 cartridge

Comment: you need `sudo` or write permissions to write in `/usr/lib/`

Comment: This is an OpenShift-specific question. OpenShift is a RedHat PaaS. I don't think they'll give me privileged access ;)

Comment: well you cannot write to the directory without sudo try specifying a directory where you do have write permissions.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham
Yeah, specify a writable directory. In OpenShift, everything is run via its management scripts, which do it automatically, and I'm asking how to repair them or how do they actually work.

Comment: As far as I can see, `~/python/virtualenv/bin/python` interpreter doesn't set virtualenv paths, while executing `~/python/virtualenv/bin/activate_this.py` under system-wide python interpreter does. That's why shellscripts which rely on `source activate` fail, while wsgi interface relying on `activate_this.py` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least, I've got it working. There was a mess with symlinks, `virtenv/lib64`->`../../python-2.6/virtenv/lib` was accessible only from `~/python-2.6`, which is a symlink to `~/python`, which contains `virtenv`, actually referenced by environment variables, which is another symlink pointing to `~/app-root/runtime/dependencies/python/virtenv`. As a result, virtenv python interpreter couldn't find libraries and other stuff in `virtenv/lib64` and was falling back to `/usr` prefix.

I simply pointed `lib64`->`lib` and deploy now works.

However, all this mess was somehow created by OpenShift toolchain, and I am not sure it won't break again.